# Missing return in a function expected to return 'CacheCallbackCoordinator.State'

Tags: swift, kingfisher

Updated my podfile and started getting this error in KingFisherManager.(Please help)

[image]

````
        set { stateQueue.sync { threadSafeState = newValue } }
        get { stateQueue.sync { threadSafeState } }
    }

    init(shouldWaitForCache: Bool, shouldCacheOriginal: Bool) {
        self.shouldWaitForCache = shouldWaitForCache
        self.shouldCacheOriginal = shouldCacheOriginal
        let stateQueueName = "com.onevcat.Kingfisher.CacheCallbackCoordinator.stateQueue.\(UUID().uuidString)"
        self.stateQueue = DispatchQueue(label: stateQueueName)
    }

    func apply(_ action: Action, trigger: () -> Void) {
        switch (state, action) {
        case (.done, _):
            break```
````

Comment: What's your XCode Version/Swift version, and what's the version of KingFisher you set? My guess? Using new implicit returns and you don't have the Swift version that allows it.